# Cannot show out results with SUM operator in PHP

Tags: php, sql

may I ask for help? I cannot show out the result. If I run the code without the SUM operator, it works properly. Please help, thank you very much.

```
     $sql1 ="SELECT SUM(SeatAmount) FROM reservation 
             WHERE RsvDate BETWEEN '07/01/2013' AND '07/31/2013'";

     $result1 = $con->query($sql1);

    printf('<td>'); 
    printf('<b>Seat Amount</b><br/>'); 
    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_object())
    {
        printf('

          %d<br/>',$row1->SeatAmount);
    }
```

Comment: Try running your query in a database query editor and you'll get an idea of what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql1 ="SELECT SUM(SeatAmount) AS Total FROM reservation 
         WHERE RsvDate BETWEEN '07/01/2013' AND '07/31/2013'";

 $result1 = $con->query($sql1);

printf('<td>'); 
printf('<b>Seat Amount</b><br/>'); 
while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_object())
{
    printf('

      %d<br/>',$row1->Total);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for that to work, you'd need an alias:

```
SELECT SUM(SeatAmount) AS SeatAmount
```

Answer (score 1):

what is `$row1`'s structure?

You can specify what the sum should be returned as like:

`SELECT SUM(SeatAmount) AS SeatAmount`